# How to cast Task<object> to Task<SomeType>?

Tags: c#, types, casting, task

I would like to cast a `Task<object>` to `Task<?>` at the runtime like that :

```
return task.CastTo(targetType);
```

Here is my best approach:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CastToString()
    {
        var task = CallTaskString("test");
        var casting = CastTo<string>(task);
        Assert.IsNotNull(casting);
        var targetTask = casting as Task<string>;
        Assert.IsNotNull(targetTask);
    }

    private async Task<T> CastTo<T>(Task task)
    {
       await task.ConfigureAwait(false);
        return (T)((dynamic)task).Result;
    }

    public Task<object> CallTaskString(string value)
    {
        return Task.Run<object>(() => value);
    }
```

I just want to replace the T by an argument Type targetType like that:
`public static async Task CastTo(this Task task, Type targetType)`.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think it is possible. What should the return type of the method look like? `private async Task<?> CastTo(this Task tas, Type targetType)`?

Comment: Task in the definition but in the value Task<string>

Comment: Generics are (mostly) a compile-time tool. If you can't access the concrete type of `Task<?>` in code (because it's unknown at compile-time), I don't see much benefit over just using `Task` or `Task<object>`. What is your use case for this? This smells like an XY problem.

Comment: I use ImpromptuInterface.ActLike to create a proxy object who works with sync methods but not with async because he can't cast Task<object> to Task<string>

Comment: Why do you want to cast the task and not just the result? Also, `Task<object>` is not a `Task<string>` so a cast isn't possible; you would need to perform a conversion.

Comment: Because I need to respect an interface and the methods returns a Task<string> (or other Task<int>, Task<Model> ...) and the proxy perform a Task<object> and at this moment I have an exception

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to call a generic method at runtime. Maybe this can help you :

```cs
public static class TaskExtension
{
    public static Task CastTo(this Task task, Type targetType)
    {
        var taskType = task.GetType();
        var srcType = taskType.GetGenericArguments().First();
        var method = typeof(TaskExtension).GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).Single(m => m.Name == nameof(CastToImpl)).MakeGenericMethod(srcType, targetType);
        return (Task)method.Invoke(null, new[] { task });
    }

    private static Task<R> CastToImpl<T, R>(Task<T> t)
        where R : T
    {
        return t.ContinueWith(t => (R)t.Result); 
    }
}
```

You can use like :

```cs
[TestMethod]
public void CastToString1()
{
    var task = CallTaskString("test");
    var casting = task.CastTo(typeof(string));
    Assert.IsNotNull(casting);
    var targetTask = casting as Task<string>;
    Assert.IsNotNull(targetTask);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to cast a Task to Task<?> at the runtime

That isn't possible if the `T` in `Task<T>` is anything other than object, because `Task<T>` is invariant.

You seem to be overthinking this; there's no need to invent a generic way of converting the Task, you can simply cast the `Result` of the `Task<object>`:

```
public async Task<string> SomeInterfaceMethodAsync()
{
    return (string) await SomeMethodThatReturnsTaskObjectAsync();
}
```

Comment: No good solution, I found a workaround by overriding the proxy method and pass the result in the parameters instead of return. It's dirty but it works